# How can i improve code formatting using prettier configuration

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, formatting, prettier

I am using `prettier` with `vs code` with the option `"editor.formatOnSave": true`

Here is my .prettierrc config:

```
module.exports = {
    semi: false,
    overrides: [
        {
            files: ['*.js', '*.json', '*.css'],
            options: {
                trailingComma: 'es5',
                tabWidth: 4,
                semi: true,
                singleQuote: true,
            },
        },
        {
            files: ['*.html'],
            options: {},
        },
    ],
};
```

is there a better way of doing that? and what should I put in the HTML option for a cleaner HTML code without having something like this:

```
<tr
                    ng-repeat="student in displayVars.studentsToShow track by student.id"
                >
```

my HTML files should be in the one line something like that and I am not sure what's going on

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in displayVars.studentsToShow track by student.id">
```

by the way, I am using `angulars 1` it's an old project to maintain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

we should add [printWidth](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width) option to 1000

```
module.exports = {
    semi: false,
    overrides: [
        {
            files: ['*.js', '*.json', '*.css'],
            options: {
                trailingComma: 'es5',
                tabWidth: 4,
                semi: true,
                singleQuote: true,
            },
        },

        {
            files: ['*.html'],
            options: {
                printWidth: 1000,
                tabWidth: 4,
                htmlWhitespaceSensitivity: 'ignore',
                proseWrap: 'never',
            },
        },
    ],
};
```